# Computer does not boot after changing hdd and reverting back

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bootloader, bios

1) I have an existing HDD in my computer that dual boots linux and windows using the traditional bios way.

2) I then took out the existing HDD and swap in a new HDD to install linux on it with uefi. It boots and reboots fine.

3) I took out the new HDD with uefi linux and put back the old HDD with bios dual boot. Old HDD boots fine.

4) I swap the old HDD with the new HDD that has uefi linux on it and it refuses to boot.

bootloader is grub for both HDD

Any ideas on what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Aside, what I am experiencing is similar to this link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

which says

> This is how some UEFI vendor implementations (ex. HP) will no longer recognize the drive as bootable through UEFI if you have made hardware changes, even though it worked prior to the switching, and you switched it back to the original configuration.

Comment: Did you change SATA-ports in between the swapping? Also check boot priority and UEFI/Legacy settings in BIOS.

Comment: Both HDD used the same SATA ports. Boot priority does not matter because only 1 HDD is present at any one time. CSM is enabled. I have a suspicion it might be due to secure boot which I is enabled and set to "other os".